# Scrape table on NASDAQ Website in VBA using XMLHTTP (not internet explorer)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the a table on NASDAQ Website but the code is returning blanks. I have tried everything I could but I am not able to find the error. I don't want to do this with internet explorer as a lot of users now disable internet explorer in their systems. Following is my code:

```
Public Sub GetTableMayank()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument                  
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ctxs/earnings", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.querySelector(".earnings-surprise__table")
    Dim td As Object, tr As Object, th As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each th In tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = th.innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Following is the image of the HTML
[image]

Comment: Data is added dynamically to the page. don't think you can do this with xmlhttp.

Comment: Is there any other solution then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of that page loads dynamically. You can either use selenium to scrape the content directly or use this api [url](https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/CTXS/earnings-surprise) which produces json content. In case of latter, you have to use json converter to parse the required values. However, I thought to come up with selenium oriented solution:

Grabbing results using selenium:

```
Sub ScrapeContent()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ctxs/earnings"
    Dim tRow As Object, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim driver As Object, R&, C&
    R = 1
    
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Fiscal Quarter End", "Date", "Earnings", "Forecast", "Surprise")
    
    driver.get URL
    For Each tRow In driver.FindElementsByCss(".earnings-surprise__table > .earnings-surprise__table-body > tr", timeout:=10000)
        R = R + 1: Ws.Cells(R, 1) = tRow.FindElementByCss("th[scope='row']").Text
        Ws.Cells(R, 2) = tRow.FindElementByCss("td").Text
        Ws.Cells(R, 3) = tRow.FindElementByCss("td:nth-of-type(2)").Text
        Ws.Cells(R, 4) = tRow.FindElementByCss("td:nth-of-type(3)").Text
        Ws.Cells(R, 5) = tRow.FindElementByCss("td:nth-of-type(4)").Text
    Next tRow
End Sub
```

Using [json converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON):

```
Sub GetResponse()
    Const URL$ = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/CTXS/earnings-surprise"
    Dim resp$, oElem As Variant, R&
    Dim jsonObject As Object, ws As Worksheet
    R = 1

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Fiscal Quarter End", "Date", "Earnings", "Forecast", "Surprise")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        resp = .responseText
    End With

    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(resp)

    For Each oElem In jsonObject("data")("earningsSurpriseTable")("rows")
        R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 1) = oElem("fiscalQtrEnd")
        ws.Cells(R, 2) = oElem("dateReported")
        ws.Cells(R, 3) = oElem("eps")
        ws.Cells(R, 4) = oElem("consensusForecast")
        ws.Cells(R, 5) = oElem("percentageSurprise")
    Next oElem
End Sub
```

Without using any third party library:

```
Sub GetResponse()
    Const URL$ = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/CTXS/earnings-surprise"
    Dim Elem As Object, resp$, oElem As Object
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, R&, oFiscal As Object
    Dim oDate As Object, oEps As Object, I&
    Dim oForecast As Object, oSurprise As Object
    
    R = 1
    
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Fiscal Quarter End", "Date", "Earnings", "Forecast", "Surprise")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        resp = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "rows[^[]+(.*?)}},"
        Set oElem = .Execute(resp)
        .Pattern = "({.*?})"
        Set Elem = .Execute(oElem(0))
        
        For I = 0 To Elem.count - 1
            .Pattern = "fiscalQtrEnd"":""(.*?)"","
            Set oFiscal = .Execute(Elem(I))
            .Pattern = "dateReported"":""(.*?)"","
            Set oDate = .Execute(Elem(I))
            .Pattern = "eps"":(.*?),"
            Set oEps = .Execute(Elem(I))
            .Pattern = "consensusForecast"":""(.*?)"","
            Set oForecast = .Execute(Elem(I))
            .Pattern = "percentageSurprise"":""(.*?)"""
            Set oSurprise = .Execute(Elem(I))

            R = R + 1: Ws.Cells(R, 1) = oFiscal(0).SubMatches(0)
            Ws.Cells(R, 2) = oDate(0).SubMatches(0)
            Ws.Cells(R, 3) = oEps(0).SubMatches(0)
            Ws.Cells(R, 4) = oForecast(0).SubMatches(0)
            Ws.Cells(R, 5) = oSurprise(0).SubMatches(0)
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Mar-21  4/29/2021   22:04   0.92    0
Dec-20  1/19/2021   22:33   0.81    16.05
Sep-20  10/22/2020  19:55   0.72    15.28
Jun-20  7/23/2020   23:45   0.78    26.92
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply. I am facing an issue with your solution. I cannot find any "Selenium Type Library" in my VBA Project References. Can you please suggest what is the issue here

Comment: Hey mate, I really appreciate your efforts on the selenium answer. I researched a bit and found out that I will have to install selenium for this. That will be an issue because I am making an excel application for different users (probably in 100s). I cannot ask everyone to install selenium.  But I like that API URL approach, can you please guide me on that a little.